# creating overlapping textview and webview

Tags: android, webview, textview

I have an app layout wherein i am using webview as a base with assets folder containing html files, everything is working great.
what i wish is to get a dynamic textview in same place as webview by default on activity launch, but when a user click on button i want to remove text view and replace the same with webview. can any one help me.
tried way:- I though of making two similar layouts and user response on button next same layout activity opens with webview. it lengthy way but manageable by me.

Comment: post your code whatever you did.

Comment: my question in nutshell is can i have webview and textview in same place by programming ? i have not done that.

Comment: yes you can.create xml layout which contains webview and text view in one frame layout and set visibility gone by default for webview and in java code when butten clicks set Webview visibility to visible and set visibility gone for textview

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do this way

**1) Create Layout "activity_main.xml"**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/btnChange"
        android:text="Show Webview"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="This is Textview.This is Textview.This is Textview.This is Textview.This is Textview.This is Textview.This is Textview.This is Textview.This is Textview." />
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**2) Create Java "MainActivity.java"**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webview;
    private TextView textView;
    private Button btnChange;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        btnChange = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChange);

        btnChange.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                if (webview.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    webview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    btnChange.setText("Show WebView");
                } else {
                    webview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    btnChange.setText("Show TextView");
                }

            }
        });
    }

}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]